# SDCC valid device list is missing devices

Tags: sdcc

I'm rebuilding a sdcc compiler after a mishap with my old system. I had been able to build on a pic18F4410, but my new setup does not include that in its valid device list. 
The device list it is calling valid looks very small.

```
sdcc --use-non-free -mpic16 -p18f4410 test_blinkall.c
'18f4410' was not found.
Valid devices are:
p18f242   p18f248   p18f252   p18f258
p18f442   p18f448   p18f452   p18f458
p18f1220  p18f1320  p18f2220  p18f2320
p18f2455  p18f2550  p18f4220  p18f4320
p18f4331  p18f4455  p18f4520  p18f6520
p18f6620  p18f6680  p18f6720  p18f8520
p18f8620  p18f8680  p18f8720
```

I'm not sure where this device list is getting pulled from. I had it working once before(Using that exact compile line), so I'm sure the solution is out there somewhere...

I'd like to get that list updated with pretty much all supported PIC18 devices.

SDCC version:
SDCC : mcs51/gbz80/z80/avr/ds390/pic16/pic14/TININative/xa51/ds400/hc08 2.5.6 #1249 (Sep  2 2015) (UNIX)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working - followed some instructions somewhere on installing SDCC via CVS checkout/compile. Checks out the latest of an old version. New version is 3.5, not 2.5.6.

Downloaded 3.5 release. Works fine.